# Why a dependency would not want to install when installing a library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, node-modules

I'm new at at creating node modules.

I'm currently building a component library for a React-native app.

It works fine when a component does not rely on a third-party library but when it does, it seems like installing the library does not install the dependencies.

Here's a simple example:

package.json from the component library :

```
"dependencies": {
"lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
"lottie-react-native": "^5.1.3"
```

},

Then I tried to add it as peerDependencies but it didn't solve the issue :

```
    "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*",
    "lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.3"
  },
```

(Since then I removed it from the peerDependencies).

Back to the RN project I want to implement, when installing the component library, lottie does not install.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You should not add your dependencies as peerdependencies. Read more on what that does here https://nodejs.org/uk/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Comment: What error are you getting when installing?

Comment: At first I didn't add it as peerDependencies, but it didn't work either. It does not throw any error. it just does not install so my component is not displayed.

Comment: When running yarn or npm there's very likely to be an error in your terminal when things go wrong. Did you try doing `npm install lottie-ios lottie-react-native react react-native` ?

Comment: Absolutely no error. And I expect my library to handle dependencies installation because I'm going to have lots of components using other libraries.

Comment: You properly want to take a look at the differences between `dependencies` and `peerDependencies`. In short, the former will be installed together with the main package while the latter will not. Yet, I don't know what kind of side effects you will get when you specify the same library in both, although you shouldn't do that in the first place.

Comment: @MatthewKwong I didn't add it as peerDependencies at first, but it didn't work. And I removed it since then. It was just to let people know that I tried.

Comment: @Phil   My bad. Indeed there are no errors but there are warnings saying   Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0"

Comment: Right yes, you can resolve that by passing the flag `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`. For more options look here https://github.com/npm/rfcs/discussions/283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with the dependencies used by your dependencies. Your react version is not compatible (according to npm) with the react version used by one of your dependencies. Thus conflicting in a peer dependency conflict. This is an issue if you're using npm version > 6.

You can resolve by passing the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag when running `npm install`. Resulting in: `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: The errors disappeared. lottie-ios and lottie-react-native appears in the node_modules but the component is not displayed. Though, it was working when installing the module locally. I guess you solved the issue and I might be on another problem.