# How can I create a node module using lottie-react-native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, node-modules, lottie

I'm building a React-Native component library.

I built a simple loader using **lottie-react-native**.

When installing the library locally, the component works.

After publishing the package on github and installing it, there is no error but the component is not displayed at all.

*(FYI, I first encountered an issue installing it which has been resolved here : [Why a dependency would not want to install when installing a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72935768/why-a-dependency-would-not-want-to-install-when-installing-a-library)
Now, the lottie-react-native dependencies appears in my node_modules).*

I think I spotted the issue but I'm not sure and I don't how to resolve it.

First have a look at the freshly installed library's folder tree in the node_modules folder:

[image]

At this point, the lib folder shows an error, let's open it :

[image]

Ok, let's open the TS folder and sub-folders until I reach the error:

[image]

Now the index.d.ts file containing the error:

[image]

Originally, the assets folders contains the json files needed for the Lottie view.

When running the publishing process, my src folder is compiled to TS and the .d files are created.

I think the issue could be due to some tsconfig options or maybe the way I import things, but I'm not sure.

Here's the folder structure in the **dev environnement**:

[image]

Since it works fine when the lib is installed locally, I'm pretty sure that the issue occurs when compiling to TS.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have 2 problems here.

1. `png` and `json` extension are not copied to the destination folder. You can fix this by copying manually or using [tsc-hook](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835#issuecomment-850098727).
2. `.js` extension files are not compiled. I think your `tsconfig` file has set `emitDeclarationOnly` to true. Try setting that to false.